# Is there any way of automating certain query execution and storing the O/P of that query in a excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, automation, toad

I have around 80 queries which I execute on a daily basis for monitoring purpose. All of them being SELECT queries, we capture the mostly the counts. This is turning out to be a boring task that's just running the query and manually capturing the output in an excel file.

For example, these are my queries with their sample respective outputs:

Query#1: `SELECT count(*) from table WHERE certain_condition = 'True'`
OUTPUT: 985

Query#2: `SELECT count(*) from another_table WHERE yet_another_condition = 'True'`
OUTPUT: 365

…

Query#80: `SELECT count(*) from another_table WHERE yet_another_condition = 'True'`
OUTPUT: 578

My requirement is this:

Capture the output of these 80 queries and paste them in an excel file in a certain order.
In Excel, I'll already have a heading (condition) in a cell. So I want the output of each query to be mapped to a specific cell corresponding to the heading (condition).

Is there any way of automating this boring task, or am I stuck for eternity as a bot?

PS: I am using Toad for Oracle v 12.9.0.71 database

Comment: You can definitely do that using VBA and ADO.  https://deepinthecode.com/2017/04/28/connecting-to-oracle-12g-with-the-instant-client-and-excel-vba/

Answer (score 1):

Like Tim was saying ADO is your best bet here. Lucky for you I just had to do this myself so hopefully this should work for you.

```
Sub SQLQuery(sqlServer As String, strDatabase As String, strQuery As String, _
exportLocation As Variant, strUserId As String, strPassword As String)

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

'create the Connection and Recordset objects
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'open the connection
conn.Open _
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
    "Data Source=" & sqlServer & ";" & _
    "Initial Catalog=" & strDatabase & ";" & _
    "User ID=" & strUserId & ";" & _
    "Password=" & strPassword & ";" & _
    "Trusted_Connection=" & "True" & ";"

'execute
Set rs = conn.Execute(strQuery)

'check if data exists
If Not rs.EOF Then

    'if so, copy to location
    exportLocation.CopyFromRecordset rs

    'close the recordset
    rs.Close

End If

'clean up
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

An example of using this subroutine:

```
Call SQLQuery( _
    oSERVER, _
    oDB, _
    "SELECT count(*) from table WHERE certain_condition = 'True'", _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), _
    oUSER, _
    oPW)
```

Just for reference you will likely have to enable Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library in your References for this to work.